# Take a few courses in another university

Tags: masters, europe, student-exchange

I'm a foreign (non-EU) student enrolled at the CS master's program in a European university. 
I would like to take 2-3 courses that my university doesn't offer, and the first idea that came to mind was to take them at another university (preferably also European) in another country. 
Obviously I want these courses to be counted in my diploma (assuming that they fit my program).

What you would do if you were in my place? Is there any "general" approach to my problem?

From what I've found there are a few ways:

- Go as a free mover and enrol to the courses individually (seems that not all universities offer this option)
- Go as an Erasmus student (not sure if I qualify being non-EU citizen)
- Go by direct exchange program to the university that have bilateral agreement with my university (in my case, I'm not satisfied with offered transfer destinations, so it's not really an option)
- Something else?

UPD: 
I assume there are 2 general cases:

1. My university and the university I wish to go are "partner
   universities", i.e. they have some sort of mutual agreement
2. They are not "partners universities"

Comment: It would greatly depend on your university accepting it. That may or may not be possible depending on the country you are in, the willingness and flexibility of the administration, the possible agreements with the other university, and the fitness to your program.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I've updated the post and narrowed it a bit

Comment: "What would you do if you were in my place?" seems primarily opinion-based and/or too broad. All the options you have cited are possible in principle, you should contact the relevant people at your university to discuss your specific situation.

Comment: @fkraiem I think "What would you do?" is in this special case not very broad. However, I would rephrase (interpret?) it as "What options do I have?" (which is also close to his second question).

Answer (score 2):

> Go by **direct exchange program** to the university that have bilateral
>   agreement with my university (in my case, I'm not satisfied with
>   offered transfer destinations, so it's not really an option)

That would be the easiest way.

> Go as an Erasmus student (not sure if I qualify being non-EU citizen)

If you are not qualified for **Erasmus**, you are certainly qualified for **Erasmus Mundus**. Just talk to the Erasmus coordinator at your university. If you are going with Erasmus they (should) have already taken care of the getting credits problem.

If all that does not work out, you could also **organize it yourself**. That is more work but sometimes worth it. Then you have to take care of most of the things yourself:

- Funding: 3 possible sources come to mind: the country you want to go
  to (for Germany that would be [DAAD](https://www.daad.de/deutschland/en/), but similar options also
  exist in most EU countries, e.g. France or Belgium [BAEF](http://www.baef.be)), the
  country you are comming from, or your home country.)
- Credit: Talk to the director of your program/ the dean of student
  affairs / international relations person
- Enrollment in the foreign university. You also have to apply there.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask your dean of student affairs (or whatever this is called at your institution), if your university will accept these courses. Usually they should (if these courses fit in the curriculum) but this, of course, depends.

Comment: At my institution, I would go to the director of my program.